# QTGraphicview fixed coordinate system

Tags: qt

i have a standard Graphicviewclass

```
#ifndef INPUTGRAPHICVIEW_H
#define INPUTGRAPHICVIEW_H

#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QPaintEvent>

class InputGraphicView : public QGraphicsView
{
public:
    InputGraphicView(QWidget* parent= NULL);
protected:
    //Take over the interaction
    virtual void wheelEvent(QWheelEvent* event);
    virtual void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e);
 //   void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* event);

private:
    QGraphicsScene* Scene;
    QGraphicsEllipseItem* ellipse;
    std::vector<QGraphicsPolygonItem*> polygon_graphic;
};

#endif // INPUTGRAPHICVIEW_H
```

My Problem is that i want to have a normal fixed coordinate system in the middle of the Graphicview. So that my x and y e [-5,5] not more.

But i dont understand the concept of the coordinate systems there I have my Scene where the origin(0,0) is on the middle?

I tried

```
setSceneRect(-5, -5, 5, 5);
```

but when i use my

```
void InputGraphicView::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{

    QPointF point;
    point=mapToScene(e->pos().x(),e->pos().y());
    std::cout << point.x() << ", " << point.y() << std::endl;
}
```

i get other coordinates. My origin is in the middle but i get values with 500 and more. Have you any idea what i can do? How i get a fixed coordinate system with fixed borders?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have (0, 0) in the center and 5 on edge, you also need to call `QGraphicsView::fitInView` to increase zoom cooefficient. And you use incorrect rectangle: 3rd and 4th arguments are width and height.

```
setSceneRect(-5, -5, 10, 10);
fitInView(-5, -5, 10, 10);
```

Comment: ty but i added this two lines to my code in the constructor and when i click with my mousepressevent function i get for the right top corne a value of (19,95) and i expect (5,5) dont understand why. Could it be the problem that i fixed the size of this window in design mode in my UI?

Comment: ok i i call it normal i get a window with max 5, but when i take my Graphicview from the UI and said that the baseclass is this class this is not working?

Comment: I didn't understand your last comment at all. Please show the code and error messages.

Comment: the code is working when i call my class normal. But now i tried to integrate my class in my UI i went to the designer and put a Graphicview to my UI. At this moment he take the Class Graphicview but when I can right click and change the Basis class to my class. But this only affects the mouseevent but it didnt work for my Zoom effect